# Toyota Premio SMART Key

Tags: toyota, smartkey

I have lost my `Toyota` `Premio` **Smart Key**, how do I get a **replacement**? Is there anything I should do to prevent the old key from being used if it was stolen?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Losing your car key is never cheap, especially for a "SMART" key like your if it has added functionality and what have you.

Comment: @MaxGoodridge It has Keyless entry, Boot Opener, Immoblizer On Off, and common door locking

Answer (score 2):

You need to take it to a Toyota dealership in your local area (if you have one) and see what they have to say. As you don't have the key any more (as opposed to it just being broken) you need to take it to the main dealer as they are likely the only ones that can do anything about it.